# Laravel 5.4 run Command as a job on a specific queue

Tags: laravel, command, queue

I want to run a `artisan command as a job`, i can do this the following way...

```
Artisan::queue('import:feed',
    [
      'feed_id'=>$feed_id,

      ]
);
```

How can i specify on which queue i can run the command? I want to run it on the medium queue for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

You need to overide the queue method @ **app/Console/Kernel.php**

```
 public function queue($command, array $parameters = [], $queue = 'default')
    {
        $this->app['Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Queue']->push(
            'Illuminate\Foundation\Console\QueuedJob', [$command, $parameters], $queue
        );
    }
```

And call like this:

```
Artisan::queue('import:feed',
    [
      'feed_id'=>$feed_id,

      ] ,'medium_queue'
);
```